# Pandas - Calculate mean for group over expanding window of dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate an expanding window mean grouped by dates.
As an example,

```
df_example = pd.DataFrame({
    'group' : ['a','a','b','b','a','a','b','a','b'],
    'date': ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-02','2021-01-02','2021-01-03','2021-01-04'],
    'val' : [True, True, False, True, False, False, True, True,False]
})

  group        date    val
0     a  2021-01-01   True 
1     a  2021-01-01   True 
2     b  2021-01-01  False 
3     b  2021-01-01   True 
4     a  2021-01-02  False 
5     a  2021-01-02  False
6     b  2021-01-02   True
7     a  2021-01-03   True
8     b  2021-01-04  False
```

For this, the logic I am looking for is: for each group and date, calculate the mean over all values less than or equal to the date. I have managed to do this as follows, but looking for a cleaner and more efficient way to approach it.

```
df1 = df_example.groupby(['group','date']).sum().groupby('group').cumsum() 
df2 = df_example.groupby(['group','date']).count().groupby('group').cumsum() 
df_result = df1 / df2


                       val
group date                
a     2021-01-01  1.000000
      2021-01-02  0.500000
      2021-01-03  0.600000
b     2021-01-01  0.500000
      2021-01-02  0.666667
      2021-01-04  0.500000
```

In addition to this, I would like to expand the dataframe to have observations for each date consistently across the groups, using a look back, e.g. if there was no observation on the date use the most recent value before.

```
                       val
group date                
a     2021-01-01  1.000000
      2021-01-02  0.500000
      2021-01-03  0.600000
      2021-01-04  0.600000
b     2021-01-01  0.500000
      2021-01-02  0.666667
      2021-01-03  0.666667
      2021-01-04  0.500000
```

Preferably this would be done efficiently and in a more readable way, as I am looking to perform similar logic and calculations for a number of groups and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
s = df_example.pivot_table('val', 'group', 'date', ['sum', 'count'])
s = s['sum'].cumsum(1).div(s['count'].cumsum(1)).ffill(axis=1).stack()
```

###### Explanations

1. Reshape the dataframe using `pivot_table` with aggfunc `sum` and `count`

```
      sum                                         count                                 
date  2021-01-01 2021-01-02 2021-01-03 2021-01-04 2021-01-01 2021-01-02 2021-01-03 2021-01-04
group                                                                                        
a            2.0        0.0        1.0        NaN        2.0        2.0        1.0        NaN
b            1.0        1.0        NaN        0.0        2.0        1.0        NaN        1.0
```

2. Calculate cumulative sum on `sum` and `count` columns along the columns axis, then divide `sum` by `count` to calculate expanding mean

```
date   2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03  2021-01-04
group                                                
a             1.0    0.500000         0.6         NaN
b             0.5    0.666667         NaN         0.5
```

3. Forward fill the mean values along the columns axis

```
date   2021-01-01  2021-01-02  2021-01-03  2021-01-04
group                                                
a             1.0    0.500000    0.600000         0.6
b             0.5    0.666667    0.666667         0.5
```

4. Stack the dataframe to reshape into multiindex series

```
group  date      
a      2021-01-01    1.000000
       2021-01-02    0.500000
       2021-01-03    0.600000
       2021-01-04    0.600000
b      2021-01-01    0.500000
       2021-01-02    0.666667
       2021-01-03    0.666667
       2021-01-04    0.500000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: This answer works perfectly, and is performant on my actual data set. Breaking down the steps explicitly for anyone else who might read:
(1) s = pd.pivot_table(data = df_example., values='val', index = 'group', columns='date',aggfunc = ['sum','count']
Will form a pivot table with, giving the date expansion. For grouping across multiple columns values can be replaced with a list
(2) The second line calculates a cumulative sum for each across the columns of the pivot. This gives the expanding window idea as the columns in the s dataframe are the dates.
(3) ffill replaces any missing values

Comment: @user157545 Thanks for breaking down the steps. I've also edited the answer with explanations of all the intermediate steps.